How dependant is food calorie content on cooking method?
Most food available in the supermarket is labelled with nutritional information including Energy expressed in kcal/kJ and is frequently given to 3 or even 4 significant figures.  This is defined (by the FDA as "Calories provide a measure of how much energy you get from a serving of this food".
There is a theory popularised by the 2009 book Catching Fire: How Cooking Made Us Human.  I have not read the book, but my understanding is that it postulates that the increased nutritional value of cooked food allowed us to evolve multiple features that made us the dominant species.  This would seem to indicate that the calorie content of food is highly dependant on the preparation method, in particular the presence and extent of heating of the food.
How accurate is nutritional information in the presence of different cooking methods?  How similar is the calorie content between rare and well done steak, or coleslaw and Irish cabbage?
